# Different ways to get WindowsIdentity with impersonation in aspnet app

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, impersonation

The app is running using impersonation and windows authentication. 
What is the difference of what i've got in the three cases?

- System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
  as WindowsIdentity
- WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
- ((HttpContext) context).User.Identity
  as WindowsIdentity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx) you have all the different posibilites. In your case you'll get the same for all 3 (Domain\UserName)